# iOS - retrieve phone number from contact list; when no number is available, the app crashes

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, contacts

I import a phone number to my app but when I tap a contact without phone number, my app is crashing.

my code:

```
if (ABMultiValueGetCount(phoneNumbers) > 0) {
    phone = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)
    ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phoneNumbers, 0);
} else {
    phone = @"[None]";
}
```

any suggestions?

Comment: No, not Xcode. Cocoa Touch.

Comment: You're passing an `int` where a `CFIndex` is expected, so I guess that's it (the second argument to `ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex()`). But since you provide so little information about the nature of the crash, what debugging you've done so far, etc. this is just speculation.

Comment: this is the error i get: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSCFConstantString substringFromIndex:]: Range or index out of bounds'

Comment: @user2023196 That's something, but what line? What is the stack trace? Did you try passing a `CFIndex` as the function expects?

Comment: @Carl, i'm beginning programmer. Can you give me example of passing CFIndex expects function?

Comment: @user2023196 nevermind I was mis-reading the documents, that is not your problem - a mistake on my part I apologize, `0` is a valid `CFIndex`, I had been reading something about `CFRange` and not paying close attention. You really should explain what line is crashing, and give a stack trace if possible. Add an exception breakpoint in Xcode and / or type `bt` when your debugger stops.

Comment: The error doesn't seem to be in the code you've posted. See the offending method: '[__NSCFConstantString substringFromIndex:]'.